# biholomorphic function from the disc to a domain with a cusp

Tags: geometry, complex-analysis

I'm looking for a holomorphic function from a bounded domain onto the upper half-plane and the inverse (let's call it C) of the Cayley transform does that for me, mapping the disc onto the aforementioned half-plane. However, I'd also like my function to be small - I want its complex derivative to be an $L^2$ function on its domain when viewed as a function in two real variables.
So I'm wondering if one can find a domain with an ultra-thin cusp or a thin spike (like the spike on $$\{(x,y):x>0,0<y<x^4\}$$ and a holomorphic function h to the disc such that the points near the spike are mapped near the singularity of C at 1. I would hope that precomposing with h would give me a function $C\circ h$ which grows sufficiently slowly.

I suppose that most of the biholomorphic functions guaranteed by the Riemann mapping thm will not keep the points in a small neighborhood of a point on the boundary close together.

Are there however any classical examples of such a map between the disc and a domain with a "cusp" or "spike"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I'd also like my function to be small - I want its complex derivative to be an $L^2$ function on its domain when viewed as a function in two real variables.

No such luck. The Jacobian determinant of a holomorphic function $f$ is $\lvert f'(z)\rvert^2$. So if $f \colon B \to \mathbb{H}$ is a biholomorphism, we have

$$\int_B \lvert f'(z)\rvert^2\,dx\,dy = \int_{\mathbb{H}} 1\,dx\,dy = \infty$$

by the transformation formula. The derivative of a biholomorphism is in $L^2$ if and only if the target domain has finite Lebesgue measure.